# Gihub Pages: How to merge between two (forked) repositories?

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages

I have a website (example.org) hosted on Github Pages. The content is in the `master` branch of the "production" repository of my "example" organization.

- example/production:master
- => Git example.org

I also have a fork of that repository in my personal account as repository "staging" where I actually create the content (in branch `master` but also feature branches) and prepare everything for publication. It is also published on Github Pages (as personal.github.io/example.org)

- personal/example.org:master
- (fork of example/production:master)
- => personal.github.io/example.org

This a bit complicated setup is required as a repository can only have one branch published on Github pages under one URL. To get another publicly available URL for my work-in-progress, I need to have the fork on my personal account.

In order that this works, I have to delete the `CNAME` file in my fork (otherwise it tries to publish for the same domain, which doesn't work as it is already in use) and also change same values in the `_config.yml` file for Jekyll (so internal navigation on the site works, tracking codes).

(I can't just put these file into .gitignore because then they wouldn't be in the repository, which is used for Github Pages directly...)

When I now try to create a pull request on "production" with the changes from "staging" these changes to `CNAME` and `_config.yml` are also merged back - breaking example.org in the process.

So right now I am cherry picking individual commits from "staging" to "production" - which is a real pain.

Is there a way to keep this one commit I have to do on "staging" out of the merge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the above question has two steps:

1. Change the domain of the fork from `personal.github.io/example.org` to `staging.example.org` so the CNAME file doesn't have to be delete but has to have different content, `staging.example.org`.
2. To be able to have different files in both repos while they still think they are fully merged, you have to do the following:

   Assume we have our `production` repo and `staging` repo both checked out locally, for now being identical (and having the same `CNAME` and `_config.yml`). Check out `staging`, make the changes to the files and commit and push them.

   If we were to do a normal merge to `production`, this change would now get merged over.

   But now we run these commands:

   ```
   git checkout production
   git merge --strategy=ours staging
   git push production production:master
   ```

   ([Source](https://paulhammant.com/2013/01/02/github-pages-as-cms-again/#making-sure-that-cname-change-never-gets-merged-back-to-the-main-production-site))

   `--strategy=ours` makes sure that during this merge, the `production` file remain unchanged. But the commit is still marked as merged.

   If we want, we can also edit the commit message between step 2 and 3 to be a bit more descriptive what we just did: We merged the two branches, but made it keep "our" (in this case: `production`) version of the files.

So for git the files are now merged, although they actually kept their content. As long as we don't touch them again, these files will stay different but count as "merged".

Answer (score 0):

Non-solution to the question, but solution to the problem of how to have a staging environment for something hosted on Github Pages:

Don't use Github pages (and a personal fork repo) for the staging environment but a `staging` branch and some other Jekyll host like Netlify: https://eduardoboucas.com/blog/2017/02/22/jekyll-staging-environment.html
This solves the `CNAME` file problem (as it is not relevant on Netlify).

Changes to `_config.yml` are required because of how the template of the Jekyll site is set up and includes style sheets, CSS etc. (`{{ site.baseurl }}/public/css/style.css`) and creates internal links (`{{ site.baseurl }}{{ node.url }}`). This can be fixed using relative links or using the domain root in links (e.g. `{{ site.baseurl }}/public/css/style.css` becomes `/style.css`).